# ListView – old check state on ItemCheck event

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, listview

When I Check an item on a ListView, then "ItemCheck" event occurs, but the checked value of the item returns always the old value!

Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ItemCheck` occurs when the check state of an item is about to change, allowing you to examine the old and new value, on the other side `ItemChecked` occurs after the check/uncheck is completed.